# Engine's 2nd best move

Tags: engines, analysis

Especially for checking studies (maybe also for teaching), it would be helpful to have an engine finding the second best move and assess it (or even give refutations of all alternatives). For a tablebase position, this is trivial. Can the Lichess/Stockfish engine do that? If not, do (especially online) alternatives exist?

Comment: You're asking about "multiPV" option. Lot's of websites allow that.

Comment: Hauke Reddmann, i would like to suggest my answer my chosen as accepted because i was the 1st to comment or post, namely 1st to comment 'what do you mean? there's the multiple lines thing in lichess right? guess i don't really understand your question'. Had I understood what you meant, i could've answered it 1st and fully. btw i'm going to edit my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah engines can do it. Here's how you do it on Lichess:

[image]

Then when you run the analysis the engine gives three moves. You can increase the number of lines you want as well, which can be a waste since in this particular position, Black really only has one good move (...g6) so resources spent analyzing the 2nd-best (...Ke7) and 3rd-best (...Qf6) moves are wasted.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not the biggest fan of chess dot com. As a 9LX player I of course prefer [lichess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/37401) but even chess dot com has this.

Just click show lines to get

[image]

the following

[image]

Go to settings to adjust number of lines:

[image]

---

Btw this is how it looks like on lichess:

Just 1 line:

[image]

Find multiple lines:

[image]

The final product:

[image]

---

What surprises me in particular about OP's question is that multiple lines option helps show how sharp/critical a position is. Eg I loaded a [puzzle](https://lichess.org/training/5Bypy) on lichess and here's what I have:

[image]

The red [circle/oval/ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249741/why-do-we-have-circles-for-ellipses-squares-for-rectangles-but-nothing-for-tria) shows the only good move for black (good here means winning, not winning-or-drawish). The orange [box](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13700/in-what-curricula-are-rectangles-defined-so-as-to-exclude-squares) shows there are 2 drawish moves. Finally the blue box shows the (least) bad moves (meaning [the least] winning for white). This setup of arranging by least to greatest evaluation shows that any other move is bad